# autocomplete search input (Failed to load https://proj.test/autocomplete-search?term=tes: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have a autocomplete input, when the user enters 3 letters it should appear the name of conference that matches that 3 letters or a name of a city that matches that 3 letters.

But its appearing an error: (index):1 Failed to load https://proj.test/autocomplete-search?term=tes: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://proj.test' is therefore not allowed access.

Do you know what can be the issue?

AutoComplete jQuery:

```
$("#search").catcomplete({
    source: "{{ URL::to('autocomplete-search') }}",
    minLength: 3,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.item.category=="Conferences"){
            window.location.href = ui.item.url;
        }
        else{
            $.get(ui.item.url, function(result) {
                var newConferences = '';
                let imageUrl = ! conference.image ? '/img/5.png' : conference.image;
                var placeholder = "{{route('conferences.show', ['id' => '1', 'slug' => 'demo-slug'])}}";

                $.each(result, function(index, conference) {
                    var url = placeholder.replace(1, conference.id).replace('demo-slug', conference.slug);
                    newConferences += '<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4">\n' +
'                        <div class="card box-shaddow">\n' +
'                            <img class="card-img-top" src='+ imageUrl +' alt="Card image cap">\n' +
'                            <div class="card-body">\n' +
'                                <p class="font-size-sm"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>  '+conference.start_date+'</p>\n' +
'                                <h5 class="card-title">'+conference.name+'</h5>\n' +
'                                <p class="card-text font-size-sm"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> '+conference.place+', '+conference.city+'</p>\n' +
'                            </div>\n' +
'                           <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">\n' +
'                                 <a href="' + url + '" class="btn btn-primary text-white">More</a>' +
' <span> Free</span>\n'+
'                           </div>\n' +
'                    </div></div>';
                });
                // add the HTML to the #conferences div
                $('#conferences').html(newConferences);
            }, 'json');
        }
    }
});
```

AutocompleteController:

```
class AutocompleteController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('autocomplete.index');
    }

    public function search(Request $request){
        $search = $request->term;
        $conferences = Conference::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->get();

        $cities = Conference::where('city', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')-> distinct()->get(['city']);

        $data= [];
        foreach ($conferences as $key => $value){
            $data[] = ['category'=> 'Conferences', 'value' => $value->name, 'url' => 'conference/'.$value->id.'/'.$value->slug];
        }

        foreach ($cities as $key => $value){
            $data[] = ['category'=> 'Cities', 'value' => $value->city, 'url' => 'conferences/where/city/'.$value->city];
        }
        return response($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Link is broken. Also, you can't access sites that are using external domains. You can use cUrls or guzzle for that.

Comment: Isn't the issue that you are calling https from an http (without the s)? If not, you should like into using AxiosJs as Laravel has that baked in out of the box, it ensures that that CSRF token is passed during the request.